# Как передать ид поста с которого нажали «купить» в заказ вукомерс?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Собственно есть задача передать Ид поста на котором нажали купить в кастомное поле заказа вукомерс. Пробовал записывать в куки, но не получается, я так понял вордпрес режет что то. (вот вопрос про это: https://toster.ru/q/496361)

Сессии тоже пробовал но не работает. Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: в кастомное поле - ACF?

Comment: нет, обычное поле своё, ну тоесть стандартный функционал wp. Дело не в том какое поле, а в том как записать туда нужную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о плагине **`ACF`**, то когда создаёте новую группу кастомных полей, у вас есть возможность установить правила отображения для этих полей - **`Location rules`**. Там надо установить правило: **`Тип записи`** (**`Post Type`**) **равно** (**`is equal to`**) **`product`**

[описание функционала](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/custom-location-rules/)

Comment: Нет, поле кастомное своё.

Comment: @pan1ka опишите в вопросе подробнее своё кастомное поле. А лучше установите ACF;)

Comment: Да дело не в типе поля, в том как записать туда нужную информацию.